# Combine subdomains into one domain

Tags: multi-sites, subsites

I have main website ABC.com with 5 subdomains on Drupal 6.2

The problems I'm facing are bellow:
1 - It is difficult for user content to migrate across the subdomains.
Detail: There are tabs on the top of USER PROFILE page for "My Content" and "My Images".
I was hoping that title links for all pages written by that user from all of the subdomains could be listed in that area
And also that all images from all subdomains uploaded by that user could go under "my images".

2 - Every time a change is made to the structure of the (site, taxonomy, blocks, configurations etc) the change has to be made on all 5 subdomains.currently we are doning indevidually.
Detail: Ideally, most of the administrative tasks should be implemented in a single change. 
Things like content types, meta tag and post settings, taxonomy.
The structure of pages under site building, site configuration, user permissions.
All the things that make a site consistent in its look and function.

MAIN WEBSITE - ABC.com
SUB DOMAIN 1 - one.ABC.com
SUB DOMAIN 2 - two.ABC.com
SUB DOMAIN 3 - three.ABC.com
SUB DOMAIN 4 - four.ABC.com
SUB DOMAIN 5 - five.ABC.com

Database Structure:
There is only 1 database for MAIN site plus all 5 Subdomain with total 700+ tables.
MIAN website ie(ABC.com) tables doesnt' have any db_prefix.
ABC.com tables as follow:
- access
- accesslog
- actions
- users
    .
    .
- vocabulary
- watchdog

All sub domains have a db_prefix of subdomain with their table names like:
- one_access
- one_accesslog
- one_actions
- one_users
    .
    .
- one_vocabulary
- one_watchdog

---

- two_access
- two_accesslog
- two_actions
- two_users
    .
    .
- two_vocabulary
- two_watchdog

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
zafar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) module was created for exactly the sort of use-case you're describing.

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for
>   running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a
>   single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content,
>   and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique

It'll take a fair amount of work to convert 6 individual sites into a single Domain Access site, but if that's the workflow you're looking for, I don't think you'll find an easier or more complete existing solution.

Comment: Thanks @Clive my search brings me to the same MODULE, You're right I thing this is the easiest way to manage all sub domains structure,content,taxonomy etc from main site administration using Domain Access module.